# Awk not working with both FIELDWIDTHS & OFS

Tags: awk

the script:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "20 20 20 6 2 9 3 20 20 22" ; OFS="*"} { print $1 $2 $3}' new2.txt
```

The input:

```
ACCESSORIES         CAT                 NOI                 002070  A226C300N000Accessories:        Cat,                NOI                  
ACCESSORIES         DENTISTS                                056480  A226D532 000Accessories:        Dentists'                               v
ACCESSORIES         DOG                 NOI                 002070  A226D200N000Accessories:        Dog,                NOI
```

The desired output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "20 20 20 6 2 9 3 20 20 22" ; OFS="*"} { print $1 $2 $3}' new2.txt
ACCESSORIES         *CAT                 *NOI
ACCESSORIES         *DENTISTS            *
ACCESSORIES         *DOG                 *NOI
```

But the asterisks are not in the output :(

Comment: You forgot the commas in `print $1,$2,$3`.

Comment: and are you sure you're using GNU awk (the only awk version that supports FIELDWIDTHS)?